# Is there a way to get the size of TOmniBlockingCollection of OmniThreadLibrary?

Tags: delphi, omnithreadlibrary

Is there a way to get the size (ie. the number of elements) of TOmniBlockingCollection of OmniThreadLibrary?

I checked the code, my initial conclusion is no, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What would you do with that information?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I spawn multiple threads (5 by default) to handle elements in a `TOmniBlockingCollection` but sometimes the collection has less elements than 5, thus I need that size info to avoid spawning unnecessary threads. Anyways, I've get around this limit by determining the size of my elements before it's put into `TOmniBlockingCollection`.

Comment: Why can't you remember how many items you put in?

Comment: You would be better off using a Parallel.ForEach on the TOmniBlockingCollection to create the processing threads. Gabr has a nice example here (http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2010/02/three-steps-to-blocking-collection-3.html). If you really have to do try and get the count from the collection then the only way I could think of is to use the enumerator to 'iterate' through the list and then add them to a new collection.

Comment: @Graymatter Then you might over subscribe

Comment: Why downvote without any explanation? @DavidHeffernan, of course I can remember how many items. TList and TStrings has the count property, why? Imagine in parentFunc() I have the item count, then the collection passed to childFunc() where I'll not have the item count unless I add a formal param to pass it into childFunc(). It's more about **convenience** and **clean code** but not a tech problem I couldn't get around.

Comment: @Graymatter, no, each loop of Parallel.ForEach() involves restarting my thread. Here I'm not mostly concerning the performance of restarting the thread since it's pooled in the global OTL pool, but the state of the thread execution, eg, I don't want to recreate an Internet connection in each loop of the collection.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either but the policy here is to avoid voting chatter in the question itself. So I reverted that update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the size (ie. the number of elements) of TOmniBlockingCollection of OmniThreadLibrary?

No there is not.